# Data is getting null after publishing the java Api's in server

Tags: sql-server, server, java

I exported a java api `abc.war` file deployed into the "server", which returns the `null([])` values, when I am calling `get` method from the Postman. This is working fine in local system but not in server.

```
Connection con= getConnection();
List<QuestionsModel> lstQuestions=new ArrayList<QuestionsModel>();

   try
   {
       if(con!=null)
       {
           CallableStatement cstmt = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;


            cstmt = con.prepareCall("{call GetQuestions()}");

            cstmt.execute();
            rs = cstmt.getResultSet(); 

           while (rs.next()) {   
                QuestionsModel questionsModel=new QuestionsModel();
                questionsModel.setQuestionID(rs.getInt("QuestionID"));
                questionsModel.setQuestion(rs.getString("Question"));
                lstQuestions.add(questionsModel);   
            } 

            con.close();
            System.out.println("Hello from GetQuestions Repository");
        return lstQuestions; 
       }
   } 
   catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

return lstQuestions;
```

Expected : Return list of objects(QuestionData)
Errors: No errors.

Comment: If in your local works and in your server doesn't, seems that some configuration of your server may be wrong. Did you check if the server and the database can connect to each other?

Comment: Thank you Paplusc..i am the new in java technologies